# Why would one want to allow in an echo protocol (port 7) from host router?

Tags: networking, firewall, echo

I am in the process of replacing an Ubuntu server originally designed by someone else at work. I expect there will be many issues with getting Windows (and really LabVIEW) to interface with all the different shares given the breadth of changes (this is being brought on by the Windows 7 End of Life, so we're concurrently upgrading to Windows 10).

Because of that, I'm copying the system as perfectly as I can to eliminate as many variables for error as possible, but I'm also loath to copy things that I don't understand.

In the old `ufw` setup, I can see a number of specific allowances for `ssh`, samba, and MySQL to the various machines that need them. However, there is a single rule allowing port `7/udp` from `192.168.1.1`. A quick google search informs me this is a port for the Echo Protocol.

That seems harmless enough, but it also seems pointless. Wikipedia suggests that `echo` was proposed for round trip time calculations, but I fail to see how this could be better than `ping`, especially if you have to add a `ufw` exception for it.

Does anyone know of any reason why anyone would specifically allow port `7` to a host router?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT from the response below. Which is technically correct.

Port 7 (both TCP and UDP) is used for the "echo" service.

If this service is available on a computer, UDP port 7 could be used instead of ICMP to perform a "ping"